# Is it possible to pass a parameter to mysql apache solr?

Tags: mysql, solr

Need pass userID parameter in apache solr.

Example:

> http://localhost.com:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*abc*&wt=json&indent=true&userID=THIS-PARAMETR-NEED-PASS

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds-1" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase" user="root" password="root"/>

<document name="t">

     <entity name="act" dataSource="ds-1"  query="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE UserID='THIS-PARAMETR-NEED-PASS'"> 
        <field column="Ac" name="acid"/>
        <field column="UserID" name="userid"/>
        <field column="Comment" name="comment"/>
       <entity name="m"

               query="SELECT * FROM `table2`WHERE `tid` = '${mytable.tid}'">    

              <field column="Title" name="title"/> 

    </entity>

</document>


</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you give is a bit mixed up as the url you show hints to a search request, but the configuration shows that you want to access a request parameters within a dataimport handler.

Your concrete parameter could be accessed like `${dataimporter.request.userID}`. Referring to [the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Accessing_request_parameters) you would need to alter your dataconfig like this

```
<entity name="act" dataSource="ds-1"  query="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE UserID='${dataimporter.request.userID}'">
```